# Magento 2: How can I fix my cron issue?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, crontab

I've installed Magento 2.3 on my server. Currently I am trying to activate cron, but unfortunately I always get the same notice when I try to install and run it.

```
Error during saving of crontab: sh: line 6: crontab: command not found
```

I've already googled some answers, but it didn't allow me to fix the problem.

I would be really grateful if some of you could help me.

Comment: How you are trying to install cron tab and what is your cron command?

Comment: I use the cron command of the magento website:

bin/magento cron:install
bin/magento cron:run

Comment: not clear see cron is set from cPanel either directly in linux using `crontab -e` or manual run done from linux terminal from magento root which one you have done if you used any of first two described method what is your expression of cron

Comment: I've done it via ssh, so I would say via linux terminal from magento root.

Answer (score 0):

First, Check your current user ssh , has any cronjob using `crontab -e`.

If it has then you have to command those cron using using `#`

After that you have to install magento cronjob using below command:

> php bin/magento cron:install -f